# How to arrange this php if-statement which outputs ratings (good, great, exxelent, etc.)?

Tags: php, css, if-statement

I'm using php if-statements to add classes to divs that are related to rating:

**CSS:**

```
.average .rating-result {
    color: #888; /* 0~1 votes */
}
.good .rating-result {
    color: #9a6e65; /* 2~3 votes */
}
.great .rating-result {
    color: #aa5443; /* 4~5 votes */
}
.excellent .rating-result {
    color: #bb3b22; /* 6~7 votes */
}
.brilliant .rating-result {
    color: #cc2200; /* 8~9 votes */
}
```

**PHP:**

```
 <div class="topic-like-count<?php if ( $thumbs_number == 0 || 1 ) {
 echo " good"; } elseif ( $thumbs_number == 2 || 3 ) { echo " great"; }
 elseif ( $thumbs_number == 4 || 5 ) { echo " excellent"; } elseif (
 $thumbs_number > 6 || 7 ) { echo " brilliant"; } else { echo "
 average"; }?>"> h4><?php wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(); ?></h4>
 </div>
```

**OUTPUT** example:

```
<div class="topic-like-count good">
<h4>
<div style="display: none">UA:D [1.9.10_1130]</div>
<div class="thumblock ">
<span class="rating-result">4</span>
<div class="ratingtext ">
<div class="raterclear"></div>
</div>
</h4>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to organize the PHP part. Above I discribed the idea but that code doesn't work properly.

Does anyone have any suggestion to arrange these php if-statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <div class="topic-like-count
  <?php 
    switch ($thumbs_number) {
      case 0:
      case 1: echo ' good'; break;
      case 2:
      case 3: echo ' great'; break;
      case 4:
      case 5: echo ' excellent'; break;
      case 6:
      case 7: echo ' brilliant'; break;
      default: echo ' average'; break;
    }
  ?>
  ">
  <h4><?php wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(); ?></h4>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes; I'd definitely use a case statement here. Well, in fact I'd probably just use a database lookup table that gave me back the text based on the rating when I retrieved it in the first place, but that's another story... I might also be tempted to assign the rating to a variable outside the HTML output, separating the logic from the display a bit more.

Comment: @Matt Gibson I'm a beginner. I'm already having a hard time with this. I may try what you suggested in the future.

Comment: @pritaeas one last question, how do I add the 'or more' 'or less' to that switch statement?

Comment: @alexchenco No problem. I think everyone has to do stuff this way at first; if you tried to do it "properly" from the start you'd be drowning in new concepts and get put off.

Comment: @alexchenco What do you mean by the "or more"? In this switch statement, either 0 or 1 will produce "good", for example -- have a [read of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) if you're not clear what's going on.

Comment: @Matt Gibson Something like this: `case ($totaltime < 1):` But never mind, I already got it.

Answer (score 2):

Your if syntax is wrong: 
`if ( $thumbs_number == 0 || 1 )` evaluates to:
`if ( ($thumbs_number == 0) || 1)` which is always true.

You should write: `if ( $thumbs_number == 0 ||  $thumbs_number == 1 )`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( $thumbs_number == 0 || $thumbs_number ==1 ) {
 echo " good"; } elseif ( $thumbs_number == 2 || $thumbs_number ==3 ) { echo " great"; }
 elseif ( $thumbs_number == 4 || $thumbs_number ==5 ) { echo " excellent"; } elseif (
 $thumbs_number > 6 || $thumbs_number ==7 ) { echo " brilliant"; } else { echo "
 average"; }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will cause it to always display **good**.

```
|| 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to incorporate this in a switch statment;

```
switch ( $thumbs_number ) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        $rating = 'good';
        break;
    case 2:
    case 3:
        $rating = 'great'; 
        break;
    // etc ...
}
?>

<div class="topic-like-count <?=$rating?>">
```